# Упрощение набора некоторых комманд Bash

Tags: linux, bash

Приходится запускать некоторые комманды (или последовательность) довольно часто. Например:

```
]$ for j in out/Cap*.png; do convert -strip $j WM/watermark.png -composite -quality 72 -sampling-factor 4:2:0  jpgout/$(basename $j .png)_wm.jpg; done
]$ for j in out/Cap*.png; do convert -strip $j -quality 74 -sampling-factor 4:2:0  jpgout/$(basename $j .png).jpg; done
```

Фактически всё каждый раз остается без изменений. Меняется только маска файла, и может меняться степень сжатия.
Как можно упростить этот процесс? В данный момент ищу набранную команду в истории, но это же не выход.

Знаю, что можно писать сценарий(так иногда делаю), или создать алиас. Последним не занимался, и не совсем представляю для чего они нужны.
Хотелось бы услышать мнение, как лучше в данном случае поступить. Если вопрос можно решить алиасом, нуждаюсь в подсказке, как это сделать.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Псевдонимы в Bash удобно использовать, если нужно дать короткое имя для единственной команды. Например:

```
alias ll='ls -al'
```

В вашем случае, поскольку вызывается практически мини-сценарий с циклами, есть смысл воспользоваться функцией. Преимущество тут такое — будет возможность задавать аргумнты при вызове.

```
transform() {
  local quality="$1"
  shift

  local name
  for name in "$@"; do
    local base=$(basename "$name" .png)
    convert -strip "$name" WM/watermark.png -composite -quality "$quality" -sampling-factor 4:2:0  "jpgout/${base}_wm.jpg"
    convert -strip "$name" -quality "$quality" -sampling-factor 4:2:0  "jpgout/${base}.jpg"
  done
}
```

Эта функция первым параметром считывает число, обозначающее качество выходных изображений, а далее ожидает список исходных файлов. Использовать можно так:

```
transform 72 out/Cap*.png
```

Comment: Только неясно где эту функцию сохранить.

Comment: @YuchimenkoIgor, можно в `~/.bashrc`. Тогда она будет доступна в вашем терминале.

Comment: Всё работает. Но чем такой подход отличается от обычного bash скрипта сохранённого, например, в ~/bin

Comment: В данном конкретном случае - разницы не много. Эта функция загрузится в оперативную память при старте терминальной сессии. Отдельный сценарий из bin будет загружаться в память в момент его запуска.

Comment: В таком качестве функции удобно использовать, если нет желания распределять код по разным файлам, если решение временное, или если команда должна как-то влиять на состояние уже запущенного bash.

Answer (score 0):

Вместо convert вы можете использовать mogrify она сама переберет файлы в каталоге.

https://imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php

> You can resize all your JPEG images in a folder to a maximum dimension
>   of 256x256 with this command:
>
> magick mogrify -resize 256x256 *.jpg

[Упрощение набора некоторых комманд Bash](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/990793/answer/submit)